# Video plugin in chat.

Tags: browser, plugins, gmail

I'm developing a social networking application for browsers using PHP and I want to have a chat application feature that supports video chat features like in Gmail (Google provides a browser plugin for this). Where can I find such an application or is there something available for a starting point for me to develop one on my own?

Thanks.

Comment: ...Yeah? What is your QUESTION?

Comment: i want to add a video chat application in my social networking site

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a service like ToxBox. They provide an API;
http://developers.tokbox.com/index.php/Main_Page